# Twillio Toll-Free Verification request rejected

Tags: twilio

I'm working on an appointment reminder website and trying to implement Twilio on my website. The message template is

Hi [FIRST_NAME], Your [SERVICE_REQUESTED] is confirmed on [APPOINTMENT_DATE_TIME]. [APPOINTMENT_ADDRESS], Thanks!

To unsubscribe reply STOP

---

My Toll-Free Verification request was rejected with Twilio Error Code: 30446.

I have submitted two times for verification. Unfortunately, it was rejected both times. It's pretty clear the message template and workflow. Users visit the public webpage to choose the available time slot and enter their phone number and email.

I'm wondering if is it the message template or online form where users book appointments that is the issue. I have shared both the form and message template with the Twillio verification team. I'm not sure what mistake I'm making, any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio's Error Code 30446 typically indicates a problem with the content of the message template or the messaging service setup, especially in the context of A2P (Application-to-Person) messaging and toll-free numbers. This error can arise due to issues like message content that doesn't comply with carrier regulations or missing opt-out instructions.

```js
const twilio = require('twilio');

const accountSid = 'YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'; // Replace with your Account SID
const authToken = 'YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN';   // Replace with your Auth Token
const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.create({
   body: 'Hi [FIRST_NAME], Your [SERVICE_REQUESTED] is confirmed on [APPOINTMENT_DATE_TIME]. [APPOINTMENT_ADDRESS], Thanks! To unsubscribe reply STOP',
   to: '+1234567890',  // Replace with the recipient's number
   from: '+1234567890' // Replace with your Twilio number
})
.then((message) => console.log(message.sid))
.catch((error) => console.error(error));
```